# How to get paginated runs using wandb client?

Tags: wandb

I am using the wandb API to retrieve a large number of runs for a project. Retrieving all runs at once takes a long time, so I want to fetch runs in several batches. Currently, in the wandb API, I notice that there is a per_page parameter for getting runs, but there is no page parameter. Therefore, I don't see a clear way to retrieve the next page of runs.

According to the wandb documentation:

```py
Runs(
    client: "RetryingClient",
    entity: str,
    project: str,
    filters: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    order: Optional[str] = None,
    per_page: int = 50,
    include_sweeps: bool = (True)
)
```

How can I retrieve paginated runs?